How to get the AST root of a rust file using syn crate?
I want to parse my input rust file and get its AST root as the output. The syn crate in rust does specifically that but the issue is that its return type is a File struct with the values of shebang , attrs and items.  I dont know which of the three contains the AST ( it's probably items ) .  If so how do I get the root AST from it?
I wanted something analogous the lang-c crate which has a unit type which contains the root of the AST.

What do you mean by "root AST" and why isn't it the File?

Here is an example of how File could look. I think like cafce25 that this is the root of the AST.
